# UWP GridView Vertical scrolling is not working

Tags: c#, gridview, uwp, vertical-scrolling

I have a little GridView with images. The GridView changes his method to display the images due to the VisualStates (small->1 column,medium->2 column,large->3 column).

I can't get the vertical scrolling to work.

Xaml:

```
  <GridView x:Name="MyGridView"
              Grid.Row="0" 
              IsItemClickEnabled="True" 
              ItemClick="MyGridView_ItemClick" 
              SizeChanged="MyGridView_SizeChanged" 
              ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
              ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled"
              ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled">
        <GridView.Resources>
            <Storyboard x:Name="EnterStoryboard">
                <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="MyGridView" />
            </Storyboard>
            <Storyboard x:Name="ExitStoryboard">
                <FadeInThemeAnimation TargetName="MyGridView" />
            </Storyboard>
        </GridView.Resources>
         <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Element">
                <RelativePanel x:Name="idPanel">
                    <Image Source="{x:Bind CoverImage}" />
                </RelativePanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
```

And background MyGridView_SizeChanged:

```
 private void MyGridView_SizeChanged(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var _panel = (ItemsWrapGrid)MyGridView.ItemsPanelRoot;
        var _actual = VisualStateGroup.CurrentState;
        int _gridColumnNumber;
        switch (_actual.Name) {
             case "medium":
                {
                    _gridColumnNumber = 2;
                    break;
                }
            case "large":
                {
                    _gridColumnNumber = 3;
                    break;
                }
            default:
                {
                    _gridColumnNumber = 1;
                    break;
                }
        }
        _panel.ItemWidth =  e.NewSize.Width / _gridColumnNumber;
      }
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the code you've posted is not complete, it's hard to say why your vertical scrolling is not working. The code you've posted is right and following is a complete sample that works in my side.

XAML:

```
<Page x:Class="UWPApp.MainPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      xmlns:local="using:UWPApp"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
      mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="VisualStateGroup">
                <VisualState x:Name="narrow">
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Target="textBlock.Text" Value="NARROW" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="medium">
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="520" />
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Target="textBlock.Text" Value="MEDIUM" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="large">
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="1200" />
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Target="textBlock.Text" Value="LARGE" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

        <GridView x:Name="MyGridView"
                  Grid.Row="0"
                  IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                  ItemClick="MyGridView_ItemClick"
                  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled"
                  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled"
                  SizeChanged="MyGridView_SizeChanged">
            <GridView.Resources>
                <Storyboard x:Name="EnterStoryboard">
                    <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="MyGridView" />
                </Storyboard>
                <Storyboard x:Name="ExitStoryboard">
                    <FadeInThemeAnimation TargetName="MyGridView" />
                </Storyboard>
            </GridView.Resources>
            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <RelativePanel x:Name="idPanel">
                        <Image Source="{Binding}" />
                    </RelativePanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
        </GridView>

        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" Grid.Row="1" Height="50" FontWeight="Bold" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Code-behind:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public List<string> ImageCollection = new List<string> {
        "http://az619822.vo.msecnd.net/files/CanaryIslandsTurtle_EN-US8274101746_1366x768.jpg",
        "http://az619822.vo.msecnd.net/files/ShanghaiElevatedWalkway_EN-US8623422930_1366x768.jpg",
        "http://az619822.vo.msecnd.net/files/SkunkKit_EN-US10705950046_1366x768.jpg",
        "http://az619519.vo.msecnd.net/files/RockyMtFox_EN-US11902018005_1366x768.jpg",
        "http://az608707.vo.msecnd.net/files/Burano_EN-US12610622868_1366x768.jpg",
        "http://az608707.vo.msecnd.net/files/SealionMom_EN-US13623871731_1366x768.jpg",
        "http://az608707.vo.msecnd.net/files/Kestrel_EN-US10433052515_1366x768.jpg"
    };

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        MyGridView.ItemsSource = ImageCollection;
    }

    private void MyGridView_SizeChanged(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var _panel = (ItemsWrapGrid)MyGridView.ItemsPanelRoot;
        var _actual = VisualStateGroup.CurrentState;
        int _gridColumnNumber;
        switch (_actual.Name)
        {
            case "medium":
                {
                    _gridColumnNumber = 2;
                    break;
                }
            case "large":
                {
                    _gridColumnNumber = 3;
                    break;
                }
            default:
                {
                    _gridColumnNumber = 1;
                    break;
                }
        }
        _panel.ItemWidth = e.NewSize.Width / _gridColumnNumber;
    }

    private void MyGridView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        //TODO
    }
}
```

As I don't know the details of your `data:Element`, so I just use a URL in my sample. The vertical scrolling is working well.
[image]

You can refer to this sample and if you still have problem, please feel free to tell me. Besides, I think you can also try [AdaptiveGridView XAML Control](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp-community-toolkit/controls/adaptivegridview) in [UWP Community Toolkit](https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit), it has a similar behavior like what you want.

Comment: Thanks! AdaptiveGridView seems to be a good tool. Although if the code is correct, it seems interesting for me, where the error is. The full project is reachable on github : https://github.com/szszptr/HowItSounds

Comment: @szszptr I checked your source code on GitHub. The problem is in your `RowDefinition`. while setting row's height to Auto, the row will size to fit its content. So the GridView in this row won't be able to scroll. To fix this issue, you can change the `RowDefinition` to `<RowDefinition Height="*" />` like in the above sample. The row which height is set to * will get part of the remaining height. This can limit GridView‘s height and when the height is not enough, the GridView will be scrollable.

Comment: For more info, please see [Define page layouts with XAML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/layout/layouts-with-xaml).

Comment: @jay-zuo-msft Thanks, i really appreciate your help and your time! The asterix solved the problem, i would not detect that program logic error for quite a time... You saved me from a lot of frustration. Power is in community :)